# How to call functions from a JavaScript file in HTML

Tags: javascript

Ive been trying to link my three.js function into html so that when an element is clicked by the mouse the js function runs in the external js file. I thought i had done everything right and followed correct steps but still wont work

I've tried modifying the directories for librarys and external files and moving the script tag to see if it changes anything but its the kinda thing thats meant to work but it wont so i have run out of solutions.

Ive got the js file in the same folder and i am certain the function is named correctly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title> Solar System </title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    canvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="module" src="./index.js"> </script>

  <link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js/threex.domevents.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/three.module.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/threex.linkify.js"></script>


  <div id="planet-menu">
    <ul>
      <li onclick="selectPlanet('Mercury')">Mercury</li>
      <li onclick="selectPlanet('Venus')">Venus</li>
      <li onclick="selectPlanet('Earth')">Earth</li>
      <li onclick="selectPlanet('Mars')">Mars</li>
      <li onclick="selectPlanet('Jupiter')">Jupiter</li>
      <li onclick="selectPlanet('Saturn')">Saturn</li>
      <li onclick="selectPlanet('Uranus')">Uranus</li>
      <li onclick="selectPlanet('Neptune')">Neptune</li>
    </ul>
  </div>



  <script type="module" src="./index.js "> </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see and a problem you haven't really described.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, as well as any debugging observations you have made.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you have initialized the script on the head, and at the bottom, try to remove it from the head. (it's best practice to add the script tag at the end of the body)

and if you are using `type="module"`
you should make the function global by writing the below code on your js file.

```
window.selectPanel = selectPanel;
```

or if you do not want to use the module, you can simply remove the `type="module"` form script tag

Comment: thank you removing the type wouldnt allow the project to load but adding those lines allowed it to reference and work as intended

Answer (score 6):

I see you've used `type=module`. Variables/functions defined in a Module are not globally-scoped, and are therefore the `selectPlanet()` function does not exist in the scope you're calling it.

Comment: okay i have tried changing this but still doesnt work  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./index.js"> </script>

Comment: What do you see in the browser console?